# Creating a bar chart with ggplot2 with dummy variables on x-axis as well as providing the y-values for the barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, data-visualization

my dataset has two variables that describe my observations:

1. The variable 'income in year 1978'
2. A dummy variable 0 or 1 for 'treatment status' (being in either the treatment or control group).

My objective now is to create a bar chart that describes the average income of 1978 for the treatment as well as the control group.
My code as of now:
`chart1 = ggplot(data = NSW, aes(x = treatment, y = income)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')`

What I get is this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soAuN.png)

I changed my code to this: `chart1 = ggplot(data = NSW, aes(x = treatment, y = mean(income))) + geom_bar(stat='identity')`

Which produces this bar chart: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPP4Q.png)

I'm just confused on how to tell R that I want both bars to 'stop' on the y-axis, where the respective average income for either group is being described.

Edit:
This is how the end result should look like (sorry for my bad drawing):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTuXl.jpg)
Title of the chart would be sth like: Average earnings of 1978 -- Treatment and Control Groups

Hope anybody can help me out here.
Thanks!

PS: Don't be confused, in both bar charts the variable name of income is labeld as 're78'.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me: "I'm just confused on how to tell R that I want both bars to 'stop' on the y-axis, where the respective average income for either group is being described" <- are you able to draw your expected outcome and add it to your question?

Comment: Updated my original post. Hope my drawing makes it more clear. Thanks again!

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
# Load libraries
library(ggplot)

# Create some fake data
income <- runif(n = 10, min = 0, max = 30000)
cohort <- factor(sample(x = 0:1, size = 10, replace = TRUE),
                    labels = c("control", "treatment"))
NSW <- data.frame(income, cohort)

# Plot the data
chart1 = ggplot(data = NSW, aes(x = cohort, y = income)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = "mean") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::dollar_format(),
                     expand = c(0, 0), name = "Mean Income")
chart1
```

[image: example_plot.png]